# `Math` is cloneable per Structured Cloning Algorithm?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

The following does not throw a `DataCloneError` `DOMException` in Chrome:

```
self.postMessage(Math, '*');
```

Is this the expected behavior per the [structured cloning algorithm](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#structuredclone)?

It is in use in an [IndexedDB test](https://github.com/w3c/web-platform-tests/blob/master/IndexedDB/key_invalid.htm#L74) (where the current lack of failure leads the test to consider `Math` as a cloneable (though invalid) keypath key) so I was curious...

Comment: It throws an error in FF, I'd vote for a chrome bug, although I have no exact reference. (But I though all Objects with a property holding a Function to be non-clonable).

Comment: Still not sure who is in trouble between FF and Chrome, but I'm able to create an other Object which will act the same : `var Beth = Object.create({v:1234, func:_=>{}})`. But this time both FF and chrome are happy to send it (as an empty object). Probably Chrome does create Math this way, while FF doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math`'s function properties are not enumerable (see [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-math.abs) and [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-property-attributes)), so they would be skipped by [StructuredClone](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#structuredclone).

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Math, 'abs').enumerable
```

In the `Beth` example in the comments above, `func` ends up on the prototype so it's not an "own property" and hence is ignored as well.

Seems like a bug in FF.

Comment: Pardon my lack of deeper investigation, but can I ask, is there not also something about host objects, or rather, some category I forget the name which applies to built-in JavaScript objects like `Math` that normally doesn't allow them to be cloned?

Comment: I had first been confused about whether "platform object" might apply, but then I saw that "Objects defined in the JavaScript specification are handled by the StructuredClone abstract operation directly." and `Math` is therein so defined.

Comment: I then got tripped up by the special handling of "exotic objects" (and the fact that ECMA-262 states "An ECMAScript implementation may support the evaluation of exotic function objects whose evaluative behaviour is expressed in some implementation defined form of executable code other than via ECMAScript code.") But as `Math` is not a function and I don't see `Math` listed as such a type in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-built-in-exotic-object-internal-methods-and-slots , I see those don't apply.

Comment: It's all totally obvious! :)